# MQJExplorer - how to export queue message in readable format?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ibm-mq, hp-uft

How can I export queue message in a readable format from MQJExplorer?

I have a queue which has around 2000 messages and I tried to right click on the queue and using "Backup Message to a file" option exported it to a file, but the file has a lot of junk values along with the messages which make me difficult to read.

Can anyone help me on how to export queue message in a readable format?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you are saying readable format, I am assuming the data in the messages is of type String/Text, So why not write a small Java application that browses messages from queue and writes message data to a file?

Comment: If you can use another tool, there are plenty for your purpose, like mqmon, rfhutil, qload.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer for you, as I'm not familiar with the MQJExplorer tool.

But...

IBM MQ ships with a program called 'dmpmqmsg', the purpose of this program is to allow you to move or copy messages into/out of MQ:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q117660_.htm

You need to be on MQ 8.0 or later to use it, and you could use it like this:

```
dmpmqmsg -m MYQUEUEMANAGER -i MYQUEUE -f /file/to/dump/messages/into
```

This copies the contents of the messages on queue 'MYQUEUE' from queue manager 'MYQUEUEMANAGER' into a file named 'into' in the /file/to/dump/messages directory.

Comment: By adding "-d t" as a parameter the output will be printed in a readable format